# How to use same UART for modbus instead of debug port

Tags: linux, modbus

I have a UART which is used as debug port, the same UART will be used for modbus.

- How to disable debug port(serial console) on this UART and use this UART for modbus in linux kernel.
- Will disabling from linux kernel command line(console=null) be sufficient or do I need to do any other extra changes.
- If i do "console=null" can i get debug messages in any other mechanism using ssh or rndis.

Thank You,
Anish Khanna

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more information. What hardware do you use? What do you mean with "debug port"? A serial console?

Comment: Hi Bodo, i have edited my question.  debug port means serial console. hardware is imx8.

Comment: Please add all information **to the question**. Hardware and Linux distribution might be relevant. As long as your system boots normally, there should be enough information in the syslog. Does the system use `grub` or a different bootloader? If the bootloader also uses the console you have to change its configuration as well.